# Can we call class with setter and getter as Java Bean?

Tags: java, javabeans

In bean standards, it is mentioned that it must implement serializable.

But in general developers say to create beans which means simple setter/getter.

Is bean correct terminology or any other terminology for class with setter and getter methods?

Comment: Haven't worked with Java beans in a while, but what you describe is basically POJO -- Plain Old Java Object.  It's only a bean when it's part of a Java bean framework.

Comment: "Bean" is such a loaded term these days that you shouldn't rely on everyone having the same definition for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just called a class that follows Object Oriented Programming (OOP) principles when you use getters and setters and make the fields private. 
http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/07/19/4-major-principles-of-object-oriented-programming/